# Error while getting parameters from request object containing `&` character

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get param from request object using following code.

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var query = req.query;
    var data = JSON.parse(query.param1);
}
```

This is working fine for most of the cases.

If `param1` contains `&` character then `query.param1` get values before `&` and next values are considered as new `param`.
eg
`localhost/?param1={"url":"http://s.test.com/x?format=jsonp&id=a&callback=b"}`

**Edit** original url is already `encoded`

`localhost/?param1=%7B%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fs.test.com%2Fx%3Fformat%3Djsonp%26id%3Da%26callback%3Db%22%7D`

in this case I'm getting `param1` = `{"url":"http://s.test.com/x?format=jsonp`

which is not valid `json`, so I'm getting error, currently we've solved it using regex (removing `localhost/?param1=` part of url).

What's best way to handle this use case?

**Edit** : server environment

`centos 6.5 server`

`node v0.12.7`

`express@4.13.3`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `express@4.13.3` (tried both the `simple` and `extended` query parsers).

Comment: @robertklep using `express@4.13.3` still getting error, so exprress version is not problem, please check edited question for other server environments

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/1fceb84ed3eeb6d4df6d) with the code I used to test.

Comment: @robertklep yeah url provided by me is working.
but my actual url is complex than this url and I was suspecting `&` character, I'll edit question again.

Answer (score 0):

`req.query` is already an object with express :

> An object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it is the empty object, {}.

[req.query documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your URL before calling nodejs API. And on the nodejs side, you have to decode the URL to get correct parameteres.

Comment: original url is already encoded, please check edited question